# Merge two objects, while one is inside of an array

Tags: php, laravel, object, merge

I need to merge 2 objects using PHP (Laravel) one of them is in an array, the other is a plain object, but also contains a nested object, is there any simple way to do it?

Edit: The result should be a single object

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "release_date": "1998",
    "license_plate": "098HBV",
    "state_id": 1,
    "type_id": 7,
    "created_at": "2016-11-18 11:39:19",
    "updated_at": "2016-11-18 11:39:19",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

and

```
 {
  "id": 1,
  "parent_id": null,
  "name": "Chrysler",
  "state_id": 1,
  "type_id": 1,
  "created_at": "2016-11-18 11:39:10",
  "updated_at": "2016-11-18 11:39:10",
  "deleted_at": null,
  "pivot": {
    "vehicle_id": 1,
    "brand_id": 1
  }
}
```

Desired output should be:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "release_date": "1998",
   "license_plate": "098HBV",
   "name": "Chrysler",

}
```

It has to be something similar, otherwise it would break a lot of JavaScript code connected to the first object.

Comment: Please see answer. This can return either an array or an object.

Comment: can you please post desired output also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   //Merge the two as an array
   $merged = array_merge($array,(array)$object);
   //As an object
   $merged = (object)$merged;
```

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work, gives an error message saying:
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array
It is an object retrieved from a query 
        $returnData = Vehicle::like('license_plate', $text)->get();

Comment: That code was assuming the first object you put in is an array, looks like you put in the object instead, swap the values in the functions. Tested in sandbox and it works fine.